# php Resource id #11 issue

Tags: php, mysql

The following function returns `Resource id #11`. How can I fix this with my present code?

```
function GET_PAGE() {
    global $page;
    if(isset($_GET)) {
        foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE title = '{$key}'";
            $page = mysql_query($query);
            confirm_query($page);
            return $page;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have one `}` too many, for one thing. Try changing `}}` to `}` above `return $page;`.

Comment: no 1 for function,1 for if,1 for foreach

Comment: Oops, sorry. My bad. Didn't notice that crunched up `{` in `if(isset($_GET)){foreach`. You should try and make a new line for clarity.

Comment: What is your ID name, `pages` or `page`?

Comment: pages is the table & page is variable.

Answer (score 3):

You did not fetch any row.

`mysql_query` returns an resource that has to be interpreted by one of the `mysql_fetch_*`-functions. Depending on your preferences [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) and [`mysql_fetch_object`](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) would be most appropriate.

---

btw: The MySQL-extension is deprecated. Consider switching to PDO or MySQLi:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.
>   (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Both allow you to use Prepared Statements to [properly secure](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) your database statements. **Your posted example is prone to SQL injections!!!**

[image: Exploits of a mom - xkcd]
(http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Sorry about not seeing your Tag edit, we must've done an edit at the exact same time.

Comment: Right on, just saw that :)